# glDrawBuffers causes GL_INVALID_OPERATION when setting GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 as GL_DRAW_BUFFER0

Tags: ios, opengl-es, fragment-shader

Using **OpengGL ES 3.0** on **iOS**, I want to use one fragment shader to draw to 2 different color attachments (not at the same time) using one framebuffer object (FBO). However, I get a **GL_INVALID_OPERATION** error when calling:

```
const GLenum attachments[] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1};
glDrawBuffers(1, attachments);
```

I inspected the GL state and made sure that the correct FBO is currently bound and that there is no GL_ERROR prior to this call and that GL_MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS is 4. Taking a GPU snapshot in Xcode gives this error description:

> The specified operation is invalid for the current OpenGL state

I create a framebuffer object with 2 color attachments as follows:

```
// Assuming the FBO and the 2 requried textures were correctly generated

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _fbo);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, _fbo_tex[0], 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, _fbo_tex[1], 0);

// glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) returns GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE
```

The vertex shader:

```
#version 300 es

uniform mat4 modelviewProjectionMatrix;
in vec4 position;

void main() {
    gl_Position = modelviewProjectionMatrix * position;
}
```

The fragment shader:

```
#version 300 es

uniform lowp vec4 colorIn;
layout(location = 0) out lowp vec4 colorOut;

void main() {
    colorOut = colorIn;
}
```

And here's the render code:

```
// Assuming the correct program and vertex array is bound

glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, _fbo);
{
    const GLenum attachments[] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
    glDrawBuffers(1, attachments);    // OK
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Draw red quad to GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0
}
{
    const GLenum attachments[] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1};
    glDrawBuffers(1, attachments);    // GL_INVALID_OPERATION Error
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Draw green quad to GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1
}
```

Weirdly enough, I don't get the error if I replace the second glDrawBuffers call with:

```
const GLenum attachments[] = {GL_NONE, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1};
glDrawBuffers(2, attachments);    // OK
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

But this is not the desired behaviour because the fragment shader outputs to draw buffer location 0. According to this wiki article: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Output_buffers {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1} is a valid input to glDrawBuffers so is this an iOS bug? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Desktop OpenGL is not the same thing as OpenGL ES. And the behavior of glDrawBuffers is more limited in ES for... some reason. In particular, from the ES 3.0 specification:

> An `INVALID_OPERATION` error is generated if the GL is bound to a draw framebuffer object and the *i*th argument is a value other than `COLOR_ATTACHMENTi` or `NONE`.

Note that last clause: the *i*th argument must either be `GL_NONE` or it must use the same color attachment index as the index *i*. OpenGL ES 3.0 doesn't allow you to route the FS's output location 0 to color attachment 1. The location must match the attachment index.

Why? I have no idea, but it's probably due to hardware limitations for ES 3.0 capable hardware. ES 3.1 removed this restriction, and desktop GL of course never had it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Given that glBindFragDataLocation doesn't exist on OpenGL ES, is there any way to change the fragment shader's output index dynamically? Or is the only alternative to create two identical shaders, one with layout(location = 0) ... and the other with layout(location = 1) ... and then switch the program before the respective draw calls?

Comment: @Chewy: `glBindFragDataLocation` doesn't dynamically allow you to change the FS's output index. It only takes effect upon a call to `glLinkProgram`. In any case, your alternatives are to either create two different programs or two different FBOs.

Comment: Good to know! What about creating one FS that writes the same value to 2 outputs: layout(location = 0)... and layout(location = 1) and then use glDrawBuffers(1, {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0}) and glDrawBuffers(2, {GL_NONE, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1}) respectively before the draw calls? It probably goes beyond the scope of this question but do you have any experience regarding performance for these three alternatives?